# How to use twitter bootstrap on Laravel 5 with Composer

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap on laravel 5 with using composer.

I have installed `twbs/bootstrap` with composer:

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap
```

I am writing form elements on view  which showed below

```
 {!! Form::open() !!}

    <div class="form-group">


    {!! Form::label('name','Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name',null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}



    </div>


    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

But bootstrap doesnt work!

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you may not included it in your laravel application, i.e. you installed via composer, check if it included in your template

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to the composer.json file

like `"twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master"`

and then run composer update on your project.

**OR**
Since you are running with Laravel 5, I would recommend using a combo of Laravel Elixir and let gulp and bower handle the rest for you.
Please refer to the written tutorial on laravel-news.com

https://laravel-news.com/2015/10/setup-bootstrap-sass-with-laravel-elixir/

Comment: Thanks I will look for this link